# Style an ASP:Textbox placeholder with CSS?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have an email address `asp:TextBox` in an `asp:UpdatePanel` on my page that has a placeholder.  I need to make the placeholder text light gray without affecting the data entered by the visitor:

```
<table>  
<tr>  
</tr>  
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="EditAddressAjax" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
     <tr>
       <asp:TextBox ID="TicketUserEmail" runat="server" MaxLength="250" placeholder="Tickets will be emailed to this address."></asp:TextBox>
     </tr>
etc.
```

I can't figure out the CSS I need to do this.  `placeholder` doesn't even show in intellisense.  I only want to affect this field in my page/site.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
:placeholder-shown {
  color: orange;
}
```

And for all browsers:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Safari, Chrome and Opera */
  color: orange;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox */
  color: orange;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: orange;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Edge */
  color: orange;
}

:placeholder-shown { /* Default */
  color: orange;
}
```

Comment: I think the update panel is messing with it.  I made the changes and Inspect in the browser says it *should* be orange, but it is not.  Orange was struck out in the inspector until I added !Important and now it is showing that it is the active color in the style sheet but not working.

Comment: Would it be possible to send a link to the website? Maybe we can find something there to make it work?

Comment: Thanks for the offer, Chris, but there is no public facing site with this yet.  Besides, the powers that be decided to go a different direction so it has become a moot point.  Sorry.

Comment: No problem what so ever. Good luck in the future!